# Is there anyway for me to legally and ethically hit the whois on thousands of domains?

Tags: whois

I have a project that is building comprehensive data on thousands of companies and domain information is an important part of it, but often the whois services will say that you can't use them for high-traffic queries. So how CAN you do high-traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[www.domaintools.com](http://www.domaintools.com) has a paid service for mass whois checks.

Comment: How are THEY able to legally query the whois databases on millions of domains? Do they pay a fee to each and every registrar?

Comment: Here's [one way](https://www.arin.net/resources/request/bulkwhois.html) to go about it.